# Drools ZipKieModule Extremely High Retained Heap Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, kie

We're trying to integrate Drools in my company, in a Kafkastreams Spring Boot based application. Drools are applied using a stateless session and are fired using the .execute() method. When profiling the application we noticed a high retained value in the ZipKieModule and more specifically in the zipEntries (some of them are modules like Guava, some of them are parts of the payload we pass). I'm not quite sure whether the high value is normal, but it seems to be all in a similar range across our different deployments.

[image]

Kind of clueless in how to debug this further and would appreciate if anyone believes this is normal or what else can be done to investigate the issue further.

Thanks!

Tried to produce a heap dump, tried to investigate logs, tried to check code for any unclosed session, made sure only one session is being passed.

Comment: It depends on multiple factors. E.g. if you use executable model (which would be good), it code generates classes based on your DRL files. If you take a look into your kjar (it is basically a zip file), you should be able to see what is inside.

Comment: Hey @TiborZimányi, greatly appreciate the response! :) What do we mean by "executable model"?

When I'm checking what is the HashMap there is constructed of, it seems to be a lot of random modules and actual code pieces. The fact that the retained value remains always the same makes me think it's just the size of the packaged generated class - as you mentioned.

Comment: And another one, when building the project via Intellij (using Maven), would the KJAR be included in the target directory? cause I can't seem to find it

Comment: To better understand what the executable model is, I recommend reading this blog. I know it is a bit older now, but the concepts are still relevant. https://blog.kie.org/2018/02/the-drools-executable-model-is-alive.html. For the KJar, yes I think it should be in the target directory. It is a normal Maven project, just with different packaging specified to Maven.

Comment: The rules are held in memory after being compiled and loaded, I'm not sure why you're surprised to see that there's an increase in memory usage when you add data to memory.